# Issues with Registering PSRepository and Installing VMWare PowerCLI Module

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

My Setup: Windows 10.17134, PowerShell 5.1.17134.407

When trying to Register a new PSRepository using the Code below….

```
Register-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" –SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
```

….it gives me the following error:

> FullyQualifiedErrorId : UseDefaultParameterSetOnRegisterPSRepository,Register-PSRepository

I am not able to install the VMWare PowerCLI Module with this command:

```
Save-module -Name vmware.powercli -path c:\temp
```

….it gives me this error:

> FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.SavePackage

[image]

Comment: What version of PowerShellGet are you using? Looks like there's some issues with how `Save-Module` is working. More info on installing/updating PowerShellGet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/gallery/installing-psget

Comment: @KyleRuddy hi, I tried installing via install-module -Name PowerShellGet -force but am getting this error: NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage also update-module -Name PowerShellGet gives following error: ModuleNotInstalledUsingInstallModuleCmdlet,Update-Module but installing the newest package nuget provider worked

Comment: If you error on the first step I would be thinking firewall or connection issue. Can you paste the address in the browser and see if it gets a SOAP response

Comment: I think you need to try downloading/installing a new version of PowerShellGet, without using Install/Save-Module. You can get a new version from the PowerShellGet repo: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet

Answer (score 3):

Here are the results of a days googling

I'm running

`Register-PSRepository 
    -Name "PSGallery" 
    –SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/" 
    -InstallationPolicy Trusted`

(multiline for clarity)

and I kept getting

> Register-PSRepository : Use 'Register-PSRepository -Default' to
>   register the PSGallery repository. At line:1 char:1
>   + Register-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" –SourceLocation "https://www. ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (PSGallery:String) [Register-PSRepository], ArgumentException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UseDefaultParameterSetOnRegisterPSRepository,Register-PSRepository

I assumed this was to do with proxy settings so I tried all of the various methods of setting the proxy in powershell to no avail.

Finally I ran

`Get-PSRepository`

and discovered that the repository was already registered, it was just untrusted

So I ran

`Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted`

The *original* reason I had for doIng this is because when I run

`Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope CurrentUser`

I get

> Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search
>   criteria for the provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires
>   'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified
>   package has the tags. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope CurrentUser
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.PowerShel\u2026tallPackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider)
>   [Install-PackageProvider], Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider

Unfortunately, making the repository trusted did no help with my issue

... and the original reason for doing this was so I could run

`Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Force -Verbose -Scope CurrentUser`

Which was failing (sorry no error message, it was so long ago)

After all my fiddling however, this statement now works without error.

Not sure if it was all the proxy config, or making NuGet trusted or both

Answer (score 0):

I've been chasing this problem for days.  I isolated it to Install-PackageProvider not being able to download:

> Microsoft.PackageManagement.NuGetProvider-2.8.5.208.dll

In my case, my company does not allow us to download `DLLs` from the internet without due process.  I engaged due process and got an approved copy of the DLL.  Then it needs to be placed here:

> $env:ProgramFiles\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies\nuget\2.8.5.208\Microsoft.PackageManagement.NuGetProvider.dll

Note the version becomes a folder and is stripped from the name.

Manually doing so eliminates the need to run `Install-PackageProvider`.  Some articles state that `Import-PackageProvider` is necessary to get PowerShell to recognise it.  But, I did not need to do the Import.  Just try `Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Force` again.